# Angular / Firestore - Route guard for login screen - Is it possible to check the user that's trying to access the route?

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angular-route-guards

I have an angular application and a route guard.

If the user ends up on `domain.com/login` whilst they are logged in, I would like to forward them to another route.

However, one user account has an attribute of 'admin' in firestore (`admin: true`). Upon logging in, I perform a check on the login.component.ts to see if that Firestore node on the user account exists. If it does, I forward them to an admin panel. If it doesn't, then it indicates that it's a client that's incoming and redirects them to another component.

However, the issue I have at the moment is that I'm not sure on how to redirect the user to the appropriate component if they end up on the login screen *whilst logged in*. Below is my guard so far. As you can see, there's a question mark in the router navigate, as I'm not sure how to determine if it's an admin or not.

```
export class LoginGuardService implements CanActivate {

   constructor(
     private router: Router,
     private auth: AngularFireAuth
   ) { }

   canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
     return this.auth.authState.pipe(
       map(authState => {
         if (authState) {this.router.navigate(['/?']);}
         return !authState;
       }),
       take(1)
     )
   }
}
```

Comment: I believe 'authState' in your code should be an instance of firebase.User https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User

Answer (score 0):

This managed to work for me:

```
export class LoginGuardService implements CanActivate {

constructor(
  private router: Router,
  private auth: AngularFireAuth
) { }

canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.auth.authState.pipe(
    map(authState => {
      if (authState && authState.email.endsWith('@domain.com')) {
        this.router.navigate(['/admins']);
      } else {
        if (authState ) {
          this.router.navigate(['clients']);
        }
      }
      return !authState;
    }),
    take(1)
  )
}
}
```